# Jasypt Encryption: Possible Characters?

Tags: encryption, delimiter, jasypt

How do I know exactly what characters are used for the encrypted output using jasypt? Can I force that my output does not contain certain characters or are always **all** ASCII characters used?

Reason I am asking is that the encrypted text is part of a file with delimiters and I would like to avoid that this delimiter is part of the encrypted text. The delimiter should also not be a hidden character, like SOH, because the file can be edited manually.

Comment: Depends what encoding you use.  The output of an encryption algorithm is always raw binary data.  What you see on your screen is determined by the encoding you use.  ASCII and UTF8 aren't valid encodings to use here, which have you been using?

Comment: Documentation says

"All the String results (of encryption) are encoded in BASE64 (or hexadecimal, if you prefer),"

Comment: Figure out which one and then Google the encoding.  You'll get a listing of possible characters.

Answer (score 1):

"Base64 only uses 6 bits (corresponding to 2^6 = 64 characters) to ensure encoded data is printable and humanly readable. None of the special characters available in ASCII are used. The 64 characters (hence the name Base64) are 10 digits, 26 lowercase characters, 26 uppercase characters as well as '+' and '/'."

So, looks like I can use ASCII special characters as a delimiter.